# Invalid BOOT.INI (dual boot XP with 7)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, multi-boot, ntldr

I had Windows XP x64 as my main system, and i also had a second partition with Windows XP x64. Both booted from first partition (C:)

I then installed Windows 7 Ultimate on the first partition. I've added NTLDR using BCDEDIT. I've also copied NTLDR, NTDETECT.COM and BOOT.INI onto the drive where XP remained. However then i try to boot into Windows XP x64 i get

```
Invalid BOOT.INI file
Booting from c:\windows\
NTDETECT failed
```

I found instructions on how to fix it using a boot disk, however the partitions are on a software RAID. I've tried to boot from a customized XP CD with the drivers, however it does not offer me a Repair option for some reason - just setup.

Partitions that i have:'=

- System Reserved
- Main (Windows 7)
- Secondary (Windows XP x64)

Here's the contents of my BOOT.INI:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(3)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(3)\WINDOWS="Windows XP Professional x64 Edition" /fastdetect
```

Comment: You've made a typo. Not `BCDRDIT`, but `BCDEDIT`.

Comment: Fixed it @Nyuszika7H (could your username be any harder to type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [seems](http://michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm) like the repair isn't showing up because the CD doesn't see the XP OS.

1.Boot with your custom XP CD with drivers.

2. Press R to load the Recovery Console.
3. Type bootcfg.
4. This should fix any boot.ini errors causing setup not to see the  XP OS 
     install.
5. Try the repair install.

Answer (score 4):

I would let the freeware tool **[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1)** try and fix this for you.

[image]

> Boot into XP/Vista/7/Ubuntu/OS X and
>   more! Boot from USB, Network, ISO
>   images, Virtual Harddisks (VHD),
>   WinPE, and more! **Repair the Windows
>   bootloader**, change your boot drive,
>   create a bootable USB, and more!
>   Rename entries, set default boot
>   target, change BCD timeout, hide the
>   boot menu, and more! Create your own
>   custom boot sequence, hide drives on
>   boot, backup and restore
>   configurations, and more!

Answer (score 1):

Follow David Smith's advice and go to the recovery console. Once there however, run these commands instead of just bootcfg to repair any of these issues:

- Windows Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL)
- Corrupt registry hives
- (\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONFIG\xxxxxx)
- Invalid BOOT.INI files
- A corrupt NTOSKRNL.EXE
- A missing NT Loader (NTLDR)

There are eight commands you must enter in sequence to fix **MOST** Windows XP boot problems.

These commands are as follows:

1. C: CD ..
2. C: ATTRIB -H C:\boot.ini
3. C: ATTRIB -S C:\boot.ini
4. C: ATTRIB -R C:\boot.ini
5. C: DEL boot.ini
6. C: BOOTCFG /Rebuild
7. C: CHKDSK /R /F
8. C: FIXBOOT

Comment: You can combine those attrib commands into one statement: "attrib -h -s -r c:\boot.ini"

Comment: @Nighthawk that would work in the normal command prompt, but, as I just tried in a WinXP SP3 recovery console, there should be the three separate commands.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already investigated this forum that indicates Software RAID in XP (specifically Pro) is a bad idea?

http://icrontic.com/forum/showthread.php?t=14727

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue that persisted inspite lots of attempts to rebuild the boot ini file, MBR etc using the recovery console; and lots of messing about with easyBCD.
In the end I solved the issue by ensuring that the actual ntldr in the root folder was compatible with the version of XP Pro SP3 I was using.
I did this by searching for the latest ntldr version in the windows update folders in my Windows XP installation and simply replacing the defective one in the root folder with the most up to date one.
It appears that EasyBCD had written an older version which was causing the boot ini error message regardless of how correct the arcpaths were.
Hope this helps.