# How can I remove the bootloader from a Windows XP partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, bootloader

My laptop was originally setup with Windows XP a few years ago. When Windows 7 came out I turned it into a dual-boot PC, but the bootloader still resided in Windows XP. Then a few months ago I got a larger harddisk, so I created a fresh Windows 7 installation on it then copied over the Windows XP partition. Windows 7 works fine and Windows XP shows up in the bootloader menu, but when I try and boot WinXP it gets stuck.

I'm assuming the problem is that there's still a bootloader on the Windows XP partition which is confusing things. What tool can I use to remove it without damaging the existing bootloader?

**Update:** I've used EasyBCD and the boot is correct. When I try to boot into WinXP it passes the first screen (black with a progress bar) but gets stuck on the blue screen with a WinXP logo and a mouse pointer. The other problem is if I boot from the WinXP SP3 DVD I get a BSOD.

Comment: [Address your actual problem, not an invented problem based upon guesswork.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html)  Your guesswork is wrong for a start.  Tell people what Windows XP does — error messages, lights, and sounds — when it "gets stuck", and they'll probably then tell you that you've [asked](http://superuser.com/questions/109483/) [a duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/99807/) question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a confident user, you can read up on BCDEDIT (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(WS.10).aspx)

**OR**

You can try a third party utility like GAG (http://gag.sourceforge.net/)

**OR**

here is a simple workaround:

1. Open your system properties (right click on My Computer, properties).
2. Select the Advanced tab.
3. Click the "Startup and recovery" button.
4. Make sure the default operating system is "Windows 7" (also ensure both operating systems are in the list or this probably won't help)
5. Uncheck "Time to display list of operating systems".

Now when you restart it should just automatically boot into Windows 7.  Again, not a solution as the MBR is still jacked up, but at least it's "out of site, out of mind".